# Jquery conflict

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

There is a conflict between jquery ui and jquery validate plug-in. How do i resolve . I am using jquery ui auto complete which does not work if i include jquery validate

```
$('#term').autocomplete({
        minLength    : 4,
        source        : '/search',
        select: function(event, ui) 
        {
            window.location =  ui.item.url;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Give some more info. What conflict? What errors?

Comment: How are you configuring your jquery-validate plug-in. There are lots of automatic things it does that you can turn on and off that might interfere.

Comment: @Peeter if i simply just include the file the ui auto complete does not work.

Comment: what versions are you using?  what does the rest of your javascript looklike?  what browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old versions of jquery-validate contain their own delegate method which interferes with the new delegate method introduced in jQuery 1.4.2. Newer versions of jQuery UI might be dependent on the jQuery version of .delegate. Make sure you are using a new version of jquery-validate (like 1.8).

Comment: specfic move to 1.8 of validate